# how to call a function inside a controller in opencart

Tags: php, ajax, opencart

i have a controller that have with in let's say `thingy/stuff` directory

```
<?php public function index() { /*thingy stuff */ }

public function anotherfunction() {/*other thingy stuff*/} ?>
```

i see tthe url like `index.php?route=thingy/stuff&var=dd`

what i want is to call an $.post to this function inside that controller

so it uses another template file `thingy.tpl` and return html to use

what the URL should like ??

i searched for hours ans it sounds like there is no development documentation for open-cart out there

Comment: what is it exactly you want to do ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

let's say you have a controller called "stuff" under the thingy folder and a function called "my function" within that class, that looks like this:

```
class ControllerThingyStuff extends Controller {
    public function index() {  
  // Some code
}
public function myfunction() {
// Your code
}
}
```

if you want to directly communicate with this function using the URL you can add the function name to the end of the route parameter "route=thingy/stuff/myfunction& ..." and load the thingy.tpl inside the function and return it after rendering:

```
// some code
$this->template = 'template/product/thingy.tpl';
...
$this->response->setOutput($this->render());
```

if are using the open cart 1.5 and you want to use jQuery AJAX with JSON then you'll need to import the JSON library before rendering:

```
$this->template = 'thingy/stuff/thingy.tpl';
$json['output'] = $this->render();
$this->load->library('json');
$this->response->setOutput(Json::encode($json));
```

take a look at the checkout page to get some ideas, the default open cart 1.5 template uses the same technique to load the templates for each section.

Comment: yes thanks but how i access the POST or GET data ??

$_POST and $_GET just dont work i think due to the MVC rules 

how i access the sent data from within the Myfunction() ??

Comment: It has nothing to do with the MVC, there is no such a rule in MVC, thats the way OpenCart has implemented it! You can access the POST and GET values by calling the Request object: $this->request->get['blabla'] and $this->request->post['blabla'] :) hope that helps

Comment: I started using the OpenCart from v1.5, I'm not sure if that's the way they do it in 1.4 ! but there should be something similar :) let me know if that didn't work :)

Comment: $this->request->get, $this->request->post, and $this->request->server are in both 1.4 and 1.5 (and I think even in versions prior to that)

Answer (score 3):

It's added to the route if it's not index, which it is by default, for example

```
<?php
class ControllerThingyStuff extends Controller {

    public function index() {
        // This is called with route=thingy/stuff or thingy/stuff/index
    }

    public function something() {
        // This is called with route=thingy/stuff/something
    }
}
```

Comment: so if i want to send data i should look 

`route=thingy/stuff/something&var=dd` ??

but the data will be on post not a parametre to the function ??

Comment: No, you pass that in the data, like it shows here
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Comment: so i got partially every thing that i need but one :

when i send a post how to get inside the function ??

$_POST just dont work so there most another way to access them ; how ????